# Updating a plot in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ipywidgets

My situation is this: I am developing a Jupyter-lab notebook to exemplify engineering topics. I find myself in the need of plotting something in an axes object within a figure, and then using a slider interact changing a value to update the plot.

Here is a MWE (or at least a shorter Working Example):

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

global ax1
global fig
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

RAD = np.array([0.85, 0.85, 0.85])
ANG = np.array([np.pi/2, np.pi*(2/3+1/2), np.pi*(1/2-2/3)])
c = ax1.scatter(ANG, RAD)

ax1.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax1.set_yticklabels([])

def h(rh):   
    RADp = np.array([rh, rh, rh])
    ANGp = np.array([-np.pi/2, np.pi*(2/3-1/2), np.pi*(-1/2-2/3)])
    cp = ax1.scatter(ANGp, RADp)
    ax1.add_artist(cp)
    plt.show()

    return (rh)

interact(h, rh = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=1, step=0.001, value=1));
```

In this example I create the figure `fig` and its axes `ax1` declared as global variables (so that they will be available within function `h`. Then using `RAD` and `ANG` I create a scatter plot `c`.

Afterwards using the `interact` widget I would like to have three crosses change position along the `r` axis by changing the value of `rh` with the slider.

I don't get any error, but neither get I any crosses at all.

In the actual code I use `pcolormesh` instead of scatter.

I hope I made myself clear. I had got ti working by creating the figure and `ax1` each time the function is called, but then I added some more suff thath don't need to be plotted each time.

Thanks for taking the time to read!

Answer (score 1):

A very limited answer is that you function should return `fig` not `rh`.

Also note that you don't need the lines with `global`, and `plt.show()`

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

RAD = np.array([0.85, 0.85, 0.85])
ANG = np.array([np.pi/2, np.pi*(2/3+1/2), np.pi*(1/2-2/3)])
c = ax1.scatter(ANG, RAD)

ax1.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax1.set_yticklabels([])


def h(rh):   
    RADp = np.array([rh, rh, rh])
    ANGp = np.array([-np.pi/2, np.pi*(2/3-1/2), np.pi*(-1/2-2/3)])
    cp = ax1.scatter(ANGp, RADp)
    ax1.add_artist(cp)
    # plt.show()

    return fig

interact(h, rh = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=1, step=0.001, value=1));
```

I say limited because I think you want to update rather than add point?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  Yes in the actual code I have a colormesh that I want to update as the slider changes its value. I will implement your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

A version which is hopefully more in line with what you want

the key point being the use of `set_offsets` method to update the positions.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

RAD = np.array([0.85, 0.85, 0.85])
ANG = np.array([np.pi/2, np.pi*(2/3+1/2), np.pi*(1/2-2/3)])
c = ax1.scatter(ANG, RAD)

ax1.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax1.set_yticklabels([])


def h(rh):   
    new = [
        [-np.pi/2, rh],
        [np.pi*(2/3-1/2), rh],
        [np.pi*(-1/2-2/3), rh],
    ]
    c.set_offsets(new)

    return fig

interact(h, rh = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=1, step=0.001, value=1));
```